# How to remove duplicate rows from an array based on first column.

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following situation:

```
    >>> a # I have
    array([[0, 1],
           [0, 2],
           [0, 2],
           [1, 3],
           [1, 3],
           [2, 1]])
    >>> new_a # I want to get to
    array([[0, 1],
           [1, 3],
           [2, 1]])
```

Basically a pure numpy solution on how to remove the entire row IF there are duplicate entries in the first column. For example: The first row is [0, 1], and the second is [0,2] -- Since the 0 (first column) is duplicated, I would like to keep the first instance and remove any other ones.

I'm sure I could set up some If statements and while loops -- but I am wondering if there are more elegant solutions. Thanks!

Comment: Better answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41110552/6091685

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way to do it with [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html), taking indices of unique items along the first column and then slicing the array along the first axis with the indices:

```
_, indices = np.unique(arr[:, 0], return_index=True)
print(arr[indices, :])
# [[0 1]
#  [1 3]
#  [2 1]]
```